# Write regular expression for text file having wireshark logs and read few lines

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write regular expressions for wireshark logs captured in text file and read few lines from frames which says 'eth:ethertype:ip:tcp:http:xml' protocol in frame only.

If above frame condition match I want to read only lines -

1-  Internet Protocol Version( for Src and Dst IP's)

2- Transmission Control Protocol ( for Port's)

3- Next line of Hypertext Transfer Protocol (e.g. 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n' from 1st Frame)

4- Complete tag from 'eXtensible Markup Language' to closing </SOAP-ENV:Envelope> OR </s:Envelope> etc.

```
**Frame** 187: 852 bytes on wire (66 bits), 852 bytes captured (66 bits) on interface \Device\N, id 0
    Section number: 1
    Frame Number: 187
    Frame Length: 852 bytes (6816 bits)
    Capture Length: 852 bytes (6816 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:tcp:http:xml]
       Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.8.X.X, Dst: 1.1.X.X
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    ...0 0000 0000 0000 = Fragment Offset: 0
    Time to Live: 125
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header Checksum: 0xc511 [validation disabled]
    [Header checksum status: Unverified]
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 8, Dst Port: 49, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 786
    Source Port: 8
    Destination Port: 49
    [Stream index: 234]
    [Conversation completeness: Incomplete, DATA (15)]
    [TCP Segment Len: 64]
    Sequence Number: 26    (relative sequence number)
    Sequence Number (raw): 274913
    [Next Sequence Number: 60    (relative sequence number)]
    Acknowledgment Number: 43    (relative ack number)
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n]
            [HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
        Response Version: HTTP/1.1
        Status Code: 200
        [Status Code Description: OK]
        Response Phrase: OK
eXtensible Markup Language
    <?xml
        version="1.0"
        encoding="utf-8"
        ?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap:Body>
            <initResponse
                xmlns="http://www.test.com/Al/">
                <status>
                    <Timestamp>
                        2023-09-26T16:51:59.6468888+08:00
                        </Timestamp>
                    <Type>
                        NO PACKET
                        </Type>
                    <State>
                        CLEARED
                        </State>
                    </status>
                </initResponse>
            </soap:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

**Frame** 179: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits) on interface , id 0
    Section number: 1
    Arrival Time: Sep 26, 2023 16:52:01.174796000 Standard Time
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1695718321.174796000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000471000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 179
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:udp:data]
    Padding: 000000
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.60.X.X, Dst: 111.8.X.X
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    010. .... = Flags: 0x2, Don't fragment
    Time to Live: 64
    [Header checksum status: Unverified]
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 474, Dst Port: 271
    Source Port: 474
    Destination Port: 271
    Length: 23
    [Checksum Status: Unverified]
    [Stream index: 0]
    [Timestamps]
        [Time since first frame: 0.358386000 seconds]
        [Time since previous frame: 0.000842000 seconds]
    UDP payload (15 bytes)
Data (15 bytes)

**Frame** 190: 852 bytes on wire (66 bits), 852 bytes captured (66 bits) on interface \Device\N, id 0
    Section number: 1
    Frame Number: 190
    Frame Length: 852 bytes (816 bits)
    Capture Length: 852 bytes (816 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:tcp:http:xml]
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 1.1.X.X, Dst: 10.8.X.X
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
        010. .... = Flags: 0x2, Don't fragment
    ...0 0000 0000 0000 = Fragment Offset: 0
    Time to Live: 125
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    [Header checksum status: Unverified]
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 8, Dst Port: 49, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 786
    Source Port: 8
    Destination Port: 49
    [Stream index: 234]
    [Conversation completeness: Incomplete, DATA (15)]
    [TCP Segment Len: 64]
    Sequence Number: 26    (relative sequence number)
    Sequence Number (raw): 274913
    [Next Sequence Number: 60    (relative sequence number)]
    Acknowledgment Number: 43    (relative ack number)
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    POST /Ser1.asmx HTTP/1.1\r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): POST /Ser1.asmx HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [POST /Ser1.asmx HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
        Request Method: POST
eXtensible Markup Language
    <?xml
        version="1.0"
        encoding="utf-8"
        ?>
    <s:Envelope
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap:Body>
            <initResponse
                xmlns="http://www.test.com/Al/">
                <status>
                    <Timestamp>
                        2023-09-26T16:51:59.6468888+08:00
                        </Timestamp>
                    <Type>
                        NO PACKET
                        </Type>
                    <State>
                        CLEARED
                        </State>
                    </status>
                </initResponse>
            </soap:Body>
        </s:Envelope>
        
**Frame** 192: 852 bytes on wire (66 bits), 852 bytes captured (66 bits) on interface \Device\N, id 0
    Section number: 1
    Frame Number: 192
    Frame Length: 852 bytes (816 bits)
    Capture Length: 852 bytes (816 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:tcp:http:xml]
       Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 1.1.X.X, Dst: 10.8.X.X
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    Time to Live: 125
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header Checksum: 0xc511 [validation disabled]
    [Header checksum status: Unverified]
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 8, Dst Port: 49, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 786
    Source Port: 8
    Destination Port: 49
    [Stream index: 234]
    [Conversation completeness: Incomplete, DATA (15)]
    [TCP Segment Len: 64]
    Sequence Number: 26    (relative sequence number)
    Sequence Number (raw): 274913
    [Next Sequence Number: 60    (relative sequence number)]
    Acknowledgment Number: 43    (relative ack number)
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n]
            [HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
        Response Version: HTTP/1.1
        Status Code: 200
        [Status Code Description: OK]
        Response Phrase: OK
eXtensible Markup Language
    <?xml
        version="1.0"
        encoding="utf-8"
        ?>
    <soap:Envelope
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap:Body>
            <initResponse
                xmlns="http://www.test.com/Al/">
                <status>
                    <Timestamp>
                        2023-09-26T16:51:59.6468888+08:00
                        </Timestamp>
                    <Type>
                        NO PACKET
                        </Type>
                    <State>
                        CLEARED
                        </State>
                    </status>
                </initResponse>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
        
**Frame** 195: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits) on interface , id 0
    Section number: 1
    Encapsulation type: Ethernet (1)
    Arrival Time: Sep 26, 2023 16:52:01.174796000 Standard Time
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1695718321.174796000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000471000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 195
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:udp:data]
    Type: IPv4 (0x0800)
    Padding: 000000
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.60.X.X, Dst: 111.8.X.X
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not ECN-Capable Transport (0)
    Total Length: 43
    Identification: 0x0000 (0)
    010. .... = Flags: 0x2, Don't fragment
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
    Time to Live: 64
    Protocol: UDP (17)
    Header Checksum: 0x698b [validation disabled]
    [Header checksum status: Unverified]
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 474, Dst Port: 271
    Source Port: 474
    Destination Port: 271
    Length: 23
    Checksum: 0xa007 [unverified]
    [Stream index: 0]
    [Timestamps]
        [Time since first frame: 0.358386000 seconds]
        [Time since previous frame: 0.000842000 seconds]
    UDP payload (15 bytes)
Data (15 bytes)
```

Output from 1st Frame (which says - Protocols in frame: eth:ethertype:ip:tcp:http:xml)-

```
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.8.X.X, Dst: 1.1.X.X
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 8, Dst Port: 49, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 786
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
eXtensible Markup Language
    <?xml
        version="1.0"
        encoding="utf-8"
        ?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap:Body>
            <initResponse
                xmlns="http://www.test.com/Al/">
                <status>
                    <Timestamp>
                        2023-09-26T16:51:59.6468888+08:00
                        </Timestamp>
                    <Type>
                        NO PACKET
                        </Type>
                    <State>
                        CLEARED
                        </State>
                    </status>
                </initResponse>
            </soap:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I was trying below to capture the whole frame in python but it's not working -

```
with open(wireshark.txt) as myfile:
    content = myfile.read()

text = re.search(r'^eth:ethertype:ip:tcp:http:xml$\.(.*)</[Ss][Oo][Aa][Pp]?[-]?[Ee][Nn][Vv]:?Envelope>', content).group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have file with multiple `**Frame**` parts where the data can be optional, you first split the file to get the separate frames.

Then you could for example get the separate parts from the frame that you want by using separate patterns, and then build a dictionary with the results per frame.

The patterns use a named capture group denoted by `(?P<groupnamehere>` and then if there is a match, you can use the `.groupdict()` from the match.

If there can be one or more spaces between the words like in `Internet Protocol Version 4, Src:`  then you can replace the single space in the regular expressions with `[^\S\n]+` to match 1 or more spaces without newlines.

For example:

```
with open("wireshark.txt") as myfile:
    content = myfile.read()

    frames = re.split(r"^(?=\*\*Frame\*\*)", content, 0, re.M)
    parsedFrames = {}

    for nr, frame in enumerate(frames):
        if frame.strip() == "":
            continue
        frameDct = {}
        matchIPV = re.search(
            r"^Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: (?P<Src>[^\s,]+), Dst: (?P<Dst>[^\s,]+)",
            frame, re.M)
        if matchIPV:
            frameDct["InternetProtocolVersion"] = matchIPV.groupdict()
        matchTCP = re.search(
            r"^Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: (?P<SrcPort>\d+), Dst Port: (?P<DstPort>\d+)\b",
            frame, re.M)
        if matchTCP:
            frameDct["TransmissionControlProtocol"] = matchTCP.groupdict()
        matchProtocol = re.search(
            r"^Hypertext Transfer Protocol\n[^\S\n]*(?P<Protocol>.+)",
            frame, re.M)
        if matchProtocol:
            frameDct["HypertextTransferProtocol"] = matchProtocol.groupdict()
        matchSoap = re.search(
            r"^(?P<XML>eXtensible Markup Language\n[\s\S]*?</(?:s(?:oap)?|SOAP-ENV):Envelope>)",
            frame, re.M)
        if matchSoap:
            frameDct["SOAP"] = matchSoap.groupdict()
        parsedFrames["frame_" + str(nr)] = frameDct
```

For example, the `parsedFrames` with key frame_3 will look like:

```
 'frame_3': {'HypertextTransferProtocol': {'Protocol': 'POST /Ser1.asmx HTTP/1.1\\r\\n'},
             'InternetProtocolVersion': {'Dst': '10.8.X.X', 'Src': '1.1.X.X'},
             'SOAP': {'XML': 'eXtensible Markup Language\n'
                             '    <?xml\n'
                             '        version="1.0"\n'
                             '        encoding="utf-8"\n'
                             '        ?>\n'
                             '    <s:Envelope\n'
                             '        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"\n'
                             '        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"\n'
                             '        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">\n'
                             '        <soap:Body>\n'
                             '            <initResponse\n'
                             '                xmlns="http://www.test.com/Al/">\n'
                             '                <status>\n'
                             '                    <Timestamp>\n'
                             '                        2023-09-26T16:51:59.6468888+08:00\n'
                             '                        </Timestamp>\n'
                             '                    <Type>\n'
                             '                        NO PACKET\n'
                             '                        </Type>\n'
                             '                    <State>\n'
                             '                        CLEARED\n'
                             '                        </State>\n'
                             '                    </status>\n'
                             '                </initResponse>\n'
                             '            </soap:Body>\n'
                             '        </s:Envelope>'},
             'TransmissionControlProtocol': {'DstPort': '49', 'SrcPort': '8'}},
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @The fourth bird. It's really helping me to optimize the logic as per my requirement.